# How to stream mp3 to S3 and retrieve URL immediately?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, stream, audio-streaming

## How can I write a stream to S3 and immediately retrieve a link to read the content back?

I'd like to upload my mp3 file to S3, get the URL to the resource, and send it to the user.

Since the upload may take upwards of 10 seconds, I'd like to stream the upload and allow the user to stream it from my bucket. However, the URL does not seem to be valid until the entire file is finished uploading.

```
  const passThroughStream = new stream.PassThrough();
  myAudioStream.pipe(passThroughStream);

  const uploadParams = {
    Bucket: bucketName,
    Key: key,
    Body: readable,
  };

  s3.upload(uploadParams, function (err, data) {
       console.log("full mp3 uploaded");
  });

  // Wait 500ms for first few bytes to upload before streaming the file
  await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 500));
  const fileUrl = s3.getSignedUrl("getObject", {
    Bucket: bucketName,
    Key: key,
    Expires: 120,
  });
  console.log("File URL", fileUrl);
```

If I click into this URL, I see the following.

[image]

I cannot access the resource until the full 10 seconds are finished. I assumed I would be able to access it the moment I began the upload.

Comment: You might need to consider proxying the upload to S3 so that your proxy can stream whatever uploaded data it has seen to date.

Answer (score 4):

That is correct. Objects in Amazon S3 are either 'all there' or 'not there at all'. It is **not possible to access an object that is still uploading**.

If you wish to 'stream' an object, then you might consider using a service that specifically streams, such as **Amazon Kinesis**.

Comment: If i use Amazon Kinesis, can I get the public facing mp3 link before the upload is complete while streaming? Will this public facing mp3 link just continue to expand in length as more bytes are streamed in?

Comment: No, it isn't as simple as that. Your app will need to understand how to access a stream and request parts of it. The file will not be presented as a normal .mp3 file. You are entering the realm of complex interactions between applications.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this fits your use case, but I use a Service Worker for this.

It intercepts PUT requests to S3 and caches the resource without its signed parameters.

On GET, it matches the base URL (again, without the signed parameters) and returns it from cache if possible.

This means that you can stream straight from cache without having to wait for that upload to S3 to finish.  This is particularly useful if you're uploading an entire list of objects, one-by-one.  Or, if you're offline and are enqueuing uploads to run when you're back online later.